# Nested vmap in pmap - JAX

Tags: python, parallel-processing, jax

I currently can run simulations in parallel on one GPU using vmap. To speed things up, I want to batch the simulations over multiple GPU devices using pmap. However, when pmapping the vmapped function I get a tracing error.

The code I use to get a trajectory state is:

```
traj_state = vmap(run_trajectory, in_axes=(0, None, 0))(sim_state, timings, lambda_array)
```

where `lambda_array` parameterises each simulation, which is run by the function `run_trajectory` which runs a single simulation. I then try to nest this inside a pmap:

```
pmap(vmap(run_trajectory, in_axes=(0, None, 0)),in_axes=(0, None, 0))(reshaped_sim_state, timings, reshaped_lambda_array)
```

In doing so I get the error:

```
While tracing the function run_trajectory for pmap, this concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the value of the argument 'timings'.
```

I'm quite new to JAX and although there are documentations on errors with traced values, I'm not
very sure on how to navigate this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vmap` and `pmap` have slightly different APIs when it comes to `in_axes`.  In `vmap`, setting `in_axes=None` causes inputs to be unmapped and static (i.e. un-traced), while in `pmap` even inputs with `in_axes=None` will be unmapped but still traced:

```py
from jax import vmap, pmap
import jax.numpy as jnp

def f(x, condition):
  # requires untraced condition:
  return x if condition else x + 1

x = jnp.arange(4)
vmap(f, in_axes=(0, None))(x, True)
# Array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)

pmap(f, in_axes=(0, None))(x, True)
# ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected:
```

To ensure that your variable is untraced in `pmap`, you can partially evaluate the function; for example:

```py
from functools import partial

vmap(partial(f, condition=True), in_axes=0)(x)
# Array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)

pmap(partial(f, condition=True), in_axes=0)(x)
# Array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

In your case, applying this solution might look like this:

```py
def run(sim_state, lambda_array, timings=timings):
  return run_trajectory(sim_state, timings, lambda_array)

vmap(run)(sim_state, lambda_array)

pmap(vmap(run))(reshaped_sim_state, reshaped_lambda_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can seemingly avoid this problem by passing the timing values prior to vmapping using partial, that is:

```
run_trajectory = partial(run_trajectory, starting_time=timings)

traj_state = pmap(vmap(run_trajectory, in_axes=(0, 0)))(reshaped_sim_state, reshaped_lambda_array)
```